# 'UCS-2' not able to encode

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8

I'm trying to read the text file but it throws one error.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 12416-12416: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk
```

I've tried to ignore it also but it I not working.
Here is the code:

```
with io.open('reviews1.txt', mode='r',encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
document1=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
print(document1)
```

Comment: Try [`surrogateescape` error handler](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/text_file_processing.html#unicode-error-handlers)? Nevertheless, please [edit] your question and show full traceback.

Comment: The problem is not with reading the file (that would be a **de**coding error). It's with the `print` expression: your environment is apparently unable to process characters beyond the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), such as emoticons. Is writing to a file instead an option?

Comment: I can reproduce the error in Python 3.5 IDLE environment. However, the script runs smoothly from a console (Windows `cmd`, in my case). @lenz is right, the error is related to `print`.

Comment: Yes but how to overcome from it? @JosefZ

Comment: I have save the data first into same file. And now I am trying to read and print the data of that file. Is there anyway such that we can delete that character while writing or reading? @lenz

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can reproduce the error in [Python IDLE environment](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/idle.html) (`Python version 3.5.1, Tk version 8.6.4, IDLE version 3.5.1`). It seems to be a bug in `Tk`. However, the original script runs smoothly from a console (Windows `cmd`, in my case): `Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`.

The only way I can see could be **very slow**: the following *commented* script copies the whole document character by character eliminating all ones out of the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane).

**Edit**: I found [this (more *Python-ish*) solution (thanks to Mark Ransom)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40224054/3439404). Unfortunately, this runs in Python shell but Python console complains:

> ```
> >>> print( ''.join(c if c <= '\uffff' else ''.join(chr(x) for x in struct.unpack(
> ...   '>2H', c.encode('utf-16be'))) for c in document1)
> ... )
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
>   File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\win_unicode_console\streams.py",
> line 179, in write
>
>     return self.base.write(s)
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't encode character '\ud83d' in position 0: 
> surrogates not allowed
> >>>
> ```

-

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys, io
import os, codecs                       # for debugging

print(os.path.basename(sys.executable), sys.argv[0], '\n') # for debugging

#######################
### original answer ###
#######################
filepath = 'D:\\test\\reviews1.txt'
with io.open(filepath, mode='r',encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    document1=myfile.read() #.replace('\n', '')
    document2=u''
    for character in document1:
        ordchar = ord(character)
        if ordchar <= 0xFFFF:
            # debugging # print( 'U+%.4X' % ordchar, character)
            document2+=character
        else:
            # debugging # print( 'U+%.6X' % ordchar, '�')
            ###         �=Replacement Character; codepoint=U+FFFD; utf8=0xEFBFBD
            document2+='�'
print(document2)                        # original answer, runs universally

######################
### updated answer ###
######################
if os.path.basename(sys.executable) == 'pythonw.exe':    
    import struct
    document3 = ''.join(c if c <= '\uffff' else ''.join(chr(x) for x in struct.unpack('>2H', c.encode('utf-16be'))) for c in document1)
    print(document3)                    # Pythonw shell
else:
    print(document1)                    # Python console
```

**Output**, Pythonw shell:

> ```
> ================== RESTART: D:/test/Python/Py/q44965129a.py ==================
> pythonw.exe D:/test/Python/Py/q44965129a.py 
>
> � smiling face with smiling eyes �
> � smiling face with open mouth   �
> � angry face                     �
>
>  smiling face with smiling eyes 
>  smiling face with open mouth   
>  angry face                     
>
> >>>
> ```

**Output**, Python console:

```
==> D:\test\Python\Py\q44965129a.py
python.exe D:\test\Python\Py\q44965129a.py

� smiling face with smiling eyes �
� smiling face with open mouth   �
� angry face                     �

 smiling face with smiling eyes 
 smiling face with open mouth   
 angry face                     

==>
```

Comment: Why use `io.open` when built-in `open` does the same? Why iterating character-wise with manual checking, when `str.encode` provides the `errors='replace'` schema, which does just that for you? Don't reinvent the wheel...

Comment: @lenz **1**. I _know_ that [`io.open` is an alias for the builtin open() function](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/io.html). It's the OP's design… **2**. Did you try to apply **any** error handlers? Apparently, you didn't: you _couldn't test this, though_ ([sic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic)!)

Comment: Oh, I didn't see you took `io.open` from the OP – sorry for blaming you for that. About testing: yes, it's a pity. According to the OP's error message, there must be a Python version/implementation that has a `UCS-2` codec; maybe it's available on Windows only. Were you able to run my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with reading the file (that would be a **de**coding error).
It's with the print expression: your environment is apparently unable to process characters beyond the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), such as emoticons.

If you want to print those characters to STDOUT, you can check if your shell/IDE supports an encoding that supports all of Unicode (UTF-8, UTF-16...).
Or you switch to a different environment for running the script.

If you want to run it in the same setting, you can encode the data yourself, which gives you the option to specify a custom error handling:

```
data = document1.encode('UCS-2', errors='replace')
sys.stdout.buffer.write(data)
```

This will replace unsupported characters as `?` or some other character.
You can also specify `errors='ignore'`, which will suppress the characters.

I couldn't test this, though, because my codecs library doesn't know the UCS-2 encoding. It's an obsolete standard used by Windows until NT.