# Displaying emojis/symbols in Python using tkinter lib

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tcl, emoji

Does Tkinter support 16bit range characters, because I can not print emojis in the gui,
when printing in python terminal, it works fine

```
>> print("")
>>
```

but in tkinter, it shows this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: character U+1f618 is above the range (U+0000-U+FFFF) allowed by Tcl
```

Comment: I found out that if use the javascript format for this emoji : emoji = Label(labelframe, text= u'\uD83D\uDE05') it shows the emoji  in tkinter, however, how can i convert the emojis to javascript format in python, i used this online converter : https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/ to get this  \uD83D\uDE05, any ideas?

Comment: I would really appreciate if there are better solutions

Answer (score 5):

There's a bug in Tkinter that it doesn't transparently map this for you, and *definitely* a bug in the underlying libraries (Tcl and Tk) that the string is not accepted *as is* and needs intervention at all. The state is that the underlying libraries currently require that the non-BMP characters in strings be encoded as surrogate pairs.

A little searching here provides code for actually doing this encoding.

- [Python: Find equivalent surrogate pair from non-BMP unicode char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222971/python-find-equivalent-surrogate-pair-from-non-bmp-unicode-char)

Comment: I know it's a bug because I know there's an issue number for it. Can't be bothered to look it up. Alas, it's an unfortunately messy problem to truly fix because it breaks a bunch of non-trivial assumptions. But at least you should have a reasonable workaround now…

Comment: would you recommend using another lib for gui, such as PyQt5 ?

Comment: You're totally asking the wrong guy about that. I don't ever choose to use either Qt or GTK in my applications, but I'm deeply biased having written parts of Tk.