# Display emoji in tkinter

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter

I'm working in Ubuntu with python 3.x, I'm trying to display some emojis in tkinter. In windows I solved this problem by displaying the equivalent surrogate pair [Python: Find equivalent surrogate pair from non-BMP unicode char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222971/python-find-equivalent-surrogate-pair-from-non-bmp-unicode-char),  but in Ubuntu when I try to do this with some emojis the program crashes giving this error,

CODE:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()
x, y= 0, 0
for _ in range(100):
    canvas.create_text(x, y, text='\ud83d\ude4f', anchor=tk.NW)
    y += 10


root.mainloop()
```

ERROR:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadLength (poly request too large or internal Xlib length error)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RENDER)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  20 (RenderAddGlyphs)
  Serial number of failed request:  199
  Current serial number in output stream:  199
```

Actually I don't think that's a python problem, maybe it is an OS problem.
I haven't found so much searching for a solution.

Comment: Using surrogates is precisely the wrong thing to do here. (It's probably necessary on Windows but it's still wacky.)

Comment: and what is the correct thing to do here?

Comment: Use the proper single Unicode code point `\U0001F64F` ()

Comment: tkinter doesn't support emojis or other unicode characters, the only way for display emojis is by the equivalent surrogate pair, i yet tried as that

Comment: Hmmm, does the font you use support this glyph?

Comment: Yes, it supports them

Comment: Try looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52228940/how-can-i-enable-support-for-emoji-in-tkinter-applications

Comment: Maybe try making the emojis images and display them in-line?

Comment: Did you try different fonts with the unicode character? Perhaps Ubuntu default fonts won't work well with it, but you can test with different windows fonts and until you find one that supports it with unicode. Then you find the .ttf file for that font, transfer it to Ubuntu and specify your font using its location. Can't say for sure for emojis, but I know it works for Arial font with unicode characters for arrow symbols, so the same approach should be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem with the font. You can use the command:

```
xfd -fa "[your font here]"
```

to see all possible emojis/symbols for your font. I believe you need to have the [emojis pack for Ubuntu](https://simpleit.rocks/linux/showing-emojis-in-ubuntu-linux/) installed.

Comment: While the information in your link may solve the OP's question, answers that rely heavily on links are discouraged for [these reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/236527). Please consider updating your answer so that it is self-contained, with the minimal amount of code required to demonstrate how it works. Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).