# When a user enters an emoji into the Tkinter entry widget, an exception is thrown when .get is called on the entry

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, python-3.7

As I have found from other questions here on StackOverflow (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52228940/how-can-i-enable-support-for-emoji-in-tkinter-applications)) there is a bug in Tkinter when using Unicode for emojis.

I have implemented the function that fixes the displaying of Unicode so I can display emojis just fine using Tkinter. However, Tkinter still throws an exception when I try to get text from an entry (text box) widget that contains an emoji saying that it is unable to decode the utf-8 string.

I suspect I might be able to get around this using `tk.call` to access the underlying Tcl interpreter directly since the other question makes me think the bug is in Tkinter and not Tcl. I do not know any Tcl have have failed to find any documentation on how to use `tk.call`... Am I going down the right path or is there a better solution?

Here is the stack trace for the crash:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/phili/PycharmProjects/pychat\gui.py", line 61, in __send
    self.add_message('You: ' + replace_emoji(self.__msg_entry.get()))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2682, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: You don't include the exception trace. Including such when reporting what looks like a bug in an application library is a very good idea...

Comment: @DonalFellows I will update my question with the exception trace in a moment.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug of very long standing (which has been tricky to fix because it breaks a bunch of assumptions in subtle ways), and is caused by the underlying libraries (Tcl and Tk) only supporting the Basic Multilingual Plane of Unicode (which emoji are not on). We hope to have a workaround in place once Tk 8.7 is released.

There may also be issues in Tkinter itself that exacerbate this.

---

I've looked into this more, and it does appear to be [in place for 8.7](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/542.md), as [can be seen](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/timeline?r=utf-max). I'm not 100% sure if it is there in Tk yet (the [branch timeline](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/timeline?r=keysym-unicode) indicates perhaps not) but that's not an API change so it shouldn't be hard; there are some caveats there but I believe it will be sorted completely for 8.7.

There's also [*some* progress](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/tktview/d433c0e0add0496ef4a7) being made on this for 8.6 too. However, it uses a non-standard build mode for Tcl (defining `TCL_UTF_MAX=4`) so it is unlikely to be generally usable for Tkinter in 8.6, whereas in 8.7 it will be practical for Tkinter to build on top of it (and the bugs will become their problem).

Comment: Thank you! Is there anything I can do as a work around? I'm working on a school project that is written in Python and must support emojis. I would hate to have to rip out the whole UI code and rewrite it with a different library only for emojis.

Comment: Awkward. The time schedules for this (the maintainers of Tcl and Tk all have other jobs too) are not conducive to tight delivery schedules, and who knows what bugs lie in the Python/Tkinter part?