# Emoji's not handled properly in Rstudio while displaying output in HTML

Tags: r, utf-8, emoji

I am facing an issue while dealing with emojis on RStudio. I am using macOS and LibreOffice to open my CSV files in UTF-8 and it displays emojis perfectly. But when it comes to RStudio it cannot render it. I tried multiple techniques including things mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699271/force-character-vector-encoding-from-unknown-to-utf-8-in-r) but still facing the same issue.

Additionally, I checked the encoding of a text column of my data frame which is read using `read_csv2()` but it gives `"unknown"`

Even the locale is set as shown here:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.4

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] NLP_0.2-1         Rcpp_1.0.8.3      pillar_1.7.0      compiler_4.2.0    tools_4.2.0      
 [6] stopwords_2.3     digest_0.6.29     evaluate_0.15     lifecycle_1.0.1   tibble_3.1.7     
[11] pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_1.0.2       DBI_1.1.2         cli_3.3.0         yaml_2.3.5       
[16] parallel_4.2.0    xfun_0.31         fastmap_1.1.0     knitr_1.39        dplyr_1.0.9      
[21] xml2_1.3.3        generics_0.1.2    vctrs_0.4.1       syuzhet_1.0.6     tidyselect_1.1.2 
[26] glue_1.6.2        data.table_1.14.2 R6_2.5.1          qdapRegex_0.7.5   fansi_1.0.3      
[31] rmarkdown_2.14    lexicon_1.2.1     textclean_0.9.3   purrr_0.3.4       sentimentr_2.9.0 
[36] magrittr_2.0.3    ellipsis_0.3.2    htmltools_0.5.2   assertthat_0.2.1  utf8_1.2.2       
[41] slam_0.1-50       tm_0.7-8          crayon_1.5.1
```

Also, I checked the Global Options setting on RStudio and reinstalled it again but no promising solution.

[image]

I basically want to[image] process this emoji and show output on HTML but it seems not done properly

It would be helpful if someone can help with this.

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried [An Introduction to emojifont package
](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emojifont/vignettes/emojifont.html) or (emo(ji))[https://github.com/hadley/emo]

Comment: You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47855762/displaying-emojis-symbols-in-python-using-tkinter-lib) helpful.