# Getting proper length of emojis

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

I noticed that while you are inputting emojis in your phone message some of them take 1 character and some of them are taking 2. For example, "♊" takes 1 char but "" takes 2. In python, I'm trying to get length of emojis and I'm getting:

```
len("♊") # 3
len("") # 4
len(unicode("♊", "utf-8")) # 1 OH IT WORKS!
len(unicode("", "utf-8")) # 1 Oh wait, no it doesn't.
```

Any ideas?

This site has emojis length in `Character.charCount()` row: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F601/index.htm

Comment: Related: [How to work with surrogate pairs in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38147966/3439404).  Try something like `import unicodedata;
unistr = u'♊';
print unistr, repr( unistr), len(unistr);
for char in unistr:print len(char), char, repr(char), unicodedata.category(char), unicodedata.name(char,'private use');`

Comment: Thanks for reply this is the result of your suggestion:
`\u264a\U0001f601 u'\u264a\U0001f601' 2
1 \u264a u'\u264a' So GEMINI
1 \U0001f601 u'\U0001f601' Cn private use`
As You can see it still read each emoji as 1 character.
I did find that stack question but I'm still trying to make surrogate work.

Comment: On my terminal, `\U0001f601` is transformed to a surrogate pair in the `for …` loop as `♊ u'\u264a\U0001f601' 3`… `1 ♊ u'\u264a' So GEMINI`… `1 � u'\ud83d' Cs private use`… `1 � u'\ude01' Cs private use` (used **…** instead a newline)

Comment: I checked your code in python2.7 and python3.5 and I got same results 2 characters. Interesting that we have different terminal results.

Comment: It's because `import sys;print hex(sys.maxunicode)` returns `'0xffff'` in my `py -2` and `'0x10ffff'` in my `py -3`. Python 3 returns 1 for `len('')` (character itself) but Python 2 returns 2 (surrogate pair).

Comment: Please avoid putting answers into questions. Open [help], read [answering](http://stackoverflow.com/help/answering), especially [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Please take the 2-minute [tour] to jog your memory about how StackExchange sites work.

Answer (score 1):

Read [sys.maxunicode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html):

> An integer giving the value of the largest Unicode code point, i.e.
>   `1114111` (`0x10FFFF` in hexadecimal).
>
> Changed in version 3.3: Before [PEP 393](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393), `sys.maxunicode` used to
>   be either `0xFFFF` or `0x10FFFF`, depending on the configuration
>   option that specified whether Unicode characters were stored as
>   `UCS-2` or `UCS-4`.

The following script should work in both  Python versions 2 an 3:

```
# coding=utf-8

from __future__ import print_function
import sys, platform, unicodedata

print( platform.python_version(), 'maxunicode', hex(sys.maxunicode))
tab = '\t'
unistr = u'\u264a \U0001f601'                          ###   unistr = u'♊ '
print ( len(unistr), tab, unistr, tab, repr( unistr))
for char in unistr:
    print (len(char), tab, char, tab, repr(char), tab, 
        unicodedata.category(char), tab, unicodedata.name(char,'private use'))
```

**Output** shows consequence of different `sys.maxunicode` property value. For instance, the  character (unicode codepoint `0x1f601` above the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane)) is converted to corresponding [surrogate pair](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38147259/3439404) (codepoints `u'\ud83d'` and `u'\ude01'`) if `sys.maxunicode` results to `0xFFFF`:

```
PS D:\PShell> [System.Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

PS D:\PShell> . py -3 D:\test\Python\Py\42783173.py
3.5.1 maxunicode 0x10ffff
3      ♊    '♊ '
1      ♊      '♊'      So      GEMINI
1             ' '      Zs      SPACE
1           ''      So      GRINNING FACE WITH SMILING EYES

PS D:\PShell> . py -2 D:\test\Python\Py\42783173.py
2.7.12 maxunicode 0xffff
4      ♊    u'\u264a \U0001f601'
1      ♊      u'\u264a'    So      GEMINI
1             u' '         Zs      SPACE
1      ��     u'\ud83d'    Cs      private use
1      ��     u'\ude01'    Cs      private use
```

Note: above output examples were taken from **Unicode-aware** [Powershell-ISE console pane](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/ise/how-to-use-the-console-pane-in-the-windows-powershell-ise).