# Conversion Java escape character to Python escape character

Tags: java, python

I received a Java escape character, `\ud83d\ude0d`, how to change it to Python escape characters?

Are there any Python functions or packages for this conversion?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please explain your use case!

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147259/how-to-work-with-surrogate-pairs-in-python

Answer (score 0):

If you get the string with `requests`, you may try to use the following method

```
import json
import requests

data = requests.get(r'https://example.com').json()
```