# Encoding Emojis from text which includes escape sequence

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, encode, emoji, utf-16

I am trying to print some text with emojis from this form `text = "\\ud83d\\ude04\\n\\u3082\\u3042"`, into:

```
# my expecting output
# a new line after the emoji, then is Japanese character
>>>
もあ
```

**I have read a question about this, but just solve part of the problem:**

[Best and clean way to Encode Emojis (Python) from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52179465/best-and-clean-way-to-encode-emojis-python-from-text-file)

I followed the code mentioned in the post, and I got below result:

```
emoji_text = "\\ud83d\\ude04\\n\\u3082\\u3042".encode("latin_1")
output = (emoji_text
  .decode("raw_unicode_escape")
  .encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass')
  .decode('utf-16')
)
print(output)

>>>\nもあ
# it prints \n instead of a new line
```

Therefore, I would like to ask, how can I convert the escape sequences **\n, \t, \b** etc. while converting the emoji and text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `unicode_escape` instead of `raw_unicode_escape` will decode the `\n` as well.  Though if there is a reason you used `raw_unicode_escape` in the first place, perhaps this will not be suitable?

Your choice to encode into `"latin-1"` is vaguely odd, but perhaps there is a reason for that, too.  Perhaps you should encode into `"ascii"` and be prepared to cope with any possible fallout.

Comment: I replace it with `unicode_escape`, it works!
Actually, the reason of using `raw_unicode_escape` and `latin-1`, is just because I read it from the above post. Thus, I will change `latin-1` to `ascii` as well if `ascii` is recommended.
I am confused with text encoding.

Comment: The [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](/tags/character-encoding/info) has some background and links to more resources. For Python, probably also read Ned Batchelder's https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: Great, it will help a lot.