# Python emoji to bytes write to txt file

Tags: python

I get this error

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f525' in position 0: character maps to

I would like to write for example "" to a txt file and it should be \U0001f525 written in the txt file

Here's my code

```
test1 = f"{config['emoji']}"


with open('emoji.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(test1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
test1 = ""

with open('emoji.txt', 'w') as f:
    transformed = (test1
        .encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass')\
        .decode('utf-16')\
        .encode("raw_unicode_escape")\
        .decode("latin_1"))
    f.write(transformed)
```

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52187065/1386143)