# Big Query do not accept EMOJI

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have emojis in this format - `\U0001f924` why BigQuery(Google Data studio) does not display them, even if I saw examples that this format working for other people?

**SAMPLE:** - Second Emoji in this format `\u2614`
[image]

**Ref:** [Emoji crashed when uploading to Big Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52169443/emoji-crashed-when-uploading-to-big-query/52173847#52173847)

Based on this article it should work:  [Google \Uhhhhhhhh Format](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical)
[image]

**UPDATE 1.0:**

If I use `""` then emojis in this format `\U2714` displays emoji, this one `\U0001f680` still the same as text `U0001f680`

If I use `''` then emojis in this format `\U2714` as well as `\U0001f680` display only value `U2714 and U0001f680`

Comment: @FelipeHoffa May be you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The emoji on the question works for me with `SELECT "\U0001f680"`:

[image]

> I stored the results in a table so you can find it:

- https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/fh-bigquery:public_dump.one_emoji?tab=preview

> If you ask BigQuery to export this table to a GCS file, and bring this file into your computer, it will continue to work:

[image]

> You can download this json file and load it back into BigQuery:

- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hXASPN0J4bP0PVk20x7x6HfkAFDAD4vq/view?usp=sharing

> Let's load it into BigQuery:

[image]

> Everything works fine:

[image]

---

So the problem is in the files you are loading to BigQuery - which are not encoding emoji's appropriately.

What I don't know is how you are generating these files, nor how to fix that process. But here I have proven that for files that correctly encode emojis - you can load them into BigQuery and emojis will be preserved.

Comment: Ye, I have just tested this ..... what I do is, I'm taking this "emoji_icon":"\U0001f44d\U0001f3fb", and upload to BigQuery  with JSON auto detect schema (emoji is a STRING)

Comment: That's not a nicely encoded file. I don't know how you are creating these files, and I don't know how to nicely encode them either.