# Escaped Unicode to Emoji in Python

Tags: python, unicode, emoji

I am trying to convert Escaped Unicode into Emojis.

Example:

```
>>> emoji = ""
>>> emoji_text = "\\ud83d\\ude00"
>>> print(emoji)

>>> print(emoji_text)
\ud83d\ude00
```

instead of "\ud83d\ude00" I would like to print

I found a simple trick that works but is not practical:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('"\\ud83d\\ude00"')
''
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to work with surrogate pairs in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147259/how-to-work-with-surrogate-pairs-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example is close to JSON's `ensure_ascii=True` string output except for needing double quotes in the string.  It contains Unicode escaped high/low surrogates for a Unicode character above U+FFFF.

Note the `unicode-escape` codec can't be used alone for conversion.  It will create a Unicode string with surrogates, which is illegal.  You won't be able to print or encode the string for serialization.

```
>>> s = "\\ud83d\\ude00"
>>> s = s.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
>>> s
'\ud83d\ude00'
>>> print(s)  # UnicodeEncodeError: surrogates not allowed
```

Using the `surrogatepass` error handler with the `utf-16` codec, you can undo  the surrogates and decode the string properly.  Note that this will decode non-surrogate escape codes as well:

```py
>>> s = "Hello\\u9a6c\\u514b\\ud83d\\ude00"
>>> s.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass').decode('utf-16')
'Hello马克'
```

##### Older solution:

The following code will replace Unicode surrogates with their Unicode code point.  If you have other non-surrogate Unicode escapes, it will replace them with their code points as well.

```
import re

def process(m):
    '''process(m) -> Unicode code point

    m is a regular expression match object that has groups below:
     1: high Unicode surrogate 4-digit hex code d800-dbff
     2: low  Unicode surrogate 4-digit hex code dc00-dfff
     3: None
    OR
     1: None
     2: None
     3: Unicode 4-digit hex code 0000-d700,e000-ffff
    '''
    if m.group(3) is None:
        # Construct code point from UTF-16 surrogates
        hi = int(m.group(1),16) & 0x3FF
        lo = int(m.group(2),16) & 0x3FF
        cp = 0x10000 | hi << 10 | lo
    else:
        cp = int(m.group(3),16)
    return chr(cp)

s = "Hello\\u9a6c\\u514b\\ud83d\\ude00"
s = re.sub(r'\\u(d[89ab][0-9a-f]{2})\\u(d[cdef][0-9a-f]{2})|\\u([0-9a-f]{4})',process,s)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
Hello马克
```