# Emoji to unicode

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I was looking at https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/ and I see that they have a "JS/Java/C" section. I was wondering if anyone had the code for that in python. I can't seem to find it. Thanks!

Edit: code

```
b = ''
txt = b.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Check the C-style checkbox in the JS/Java/C section and then print this code. For example you might use something like this: print(u'\U0001f600').

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply but I'm trying to get Javascript Escape

Comment: Did you try using Python's decode function? E.g. if you have a variable x = '' then you can do something like this x.decode('utf-8').

Comment: Yes, but the result is b'\xf0\x9f\x98\x80' and I'm looking for \uD83D\uDE00

Comment: Could you provide your code snippet?

Comment: b = ''
txt = b.encode('utf-8')

Comment: You should use decode instead of encode.

Comment: @mkrieger1 No, that isn't what I'm looking for

Comment: @George AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: @oofer you need to `.encode()` (to bytes) before you `.decode(_)` (to str)

Comment: `\uD83D\uDE00` is UTF-16, not UTF-8, and representing surrogate pairs in UTF-8 like that is invalid

Comment: What if you try something like this? `x = ''` and then `unicode(x, 'utf-8')`.

Answer (score 2):

From [How to work with surrogate pairs in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38147966/4541045) (linked from duplicate [Escaped Unicode to Emoji in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54559885/escaped-unicode-to-emoji-in-python) )

> If you see '\ud83d\ude4f' Python string (2 characters) then there is a bug upstream. Normally, you shouldn't get such string. If you get one and you can't fix upstream that generates it; you could fix it using surrogatepass error handler:
>
> ```
> >>> "\uD83D\uDE00".encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass').decode('utf-16')
> ''
> ```

---

Original Answer

Perhaps you're looking for [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)?

> Given a string representing one Unicode character, return an integer representing the Unicode code point of that character. For example, ord('a') returns the integer 97 and ord('€') (Euro sign) returns 8364. This is the inverse of chr().

```py
>>> hex(ord(""))
'0x1f600'
```