# Current idiom for removing 'surrogateescape' characters fron a decoded string

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode

> Armin Ronacher, http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2013/7/2/the-updated-guide-to-unicode/
>
> If you for instance pass [the result of os.fsdecode() or equivalent] to a template engine you [sometimes get a UnicodeEncodeError] somewhere else entirely and because the encoding happens at a much later stage you no longer know why the string was incorrect. If you detect that error when it happens the issue becomes much easier to debug

Armin suggests a function

```
def remove_surrogate_escaping(s, method='ignore'):
    assert method in ('ignore', 'replace'), 'invalid removal method'
    return s.encode('utf-8', method).decode('utf-8')
```

> Nick Coghlan, 2014, [[Python-Dev] Cleaning up surrogate escaped strings](https://grokbase.com/t/python/python-dev/148wgw15m3/cleaning-up-surrogate-escaped-strings-was-bytes-path-related-questions-for-guido)
>
> The current proposal on the issue tracker is to ... take advantage of
>   the existing error handlers:
>
> ```
> def convert_surrogateescape(data, errors='replace'):
>     return data.encode('utf-8', 'surrogateescape').decode('utf-8', errors)
> ```
>
> That code is short, but semantically dense - it took a few iterations to
>   come up with that version. (Added bonus: once you're alerted to the
>   possibility, it's trivial to write your own version for existing Python 3
>   versions. The standard name just makes it easier to look up when you come
>   across it in a piece of code, and provides the option of optimising it
>   later if it ever seems worth the extra work)

The functions are slightly different.  The second was written with knowledge of the first.

Since Python 3.5, the `backslashreplace` error handler now works on decoding as well as encoding.  The first approach is not designed to use `backslashreplace` e.g. an error decoding the byte 0xff would get printed as "\udcff".  The second approach is designed to solve this; it would print "\xff".

If you did not need `backslashreplace`, you might prefer the first version if you had the misfortune to be supporting Python < 3.5 (including polyglot 2/3 code, ouch).

### Question

Is there a better idiom for this purpose yet?  Or do we still use this drop-in function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nick referred to an issue for [adding such a function](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/63014) to the `codecs` module.  As of 2024, the function has not been added, and the ticket remains open.

---

[The latest comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/63014#issuecomment-1093625396) says

> Nick Coghlan, 2018
>
> A recent [discussion on python-ideas](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2018-January/048583.html) also introduced me to the third party library, "[ftfy](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)", which offers a wide range of tools for cleaning up improperly decoded data.
>
> That includes a lone surrogate fixer: [`ftfy.fixes.fix_surrogates(text)`](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#ftfy.fixes.fix_surrogates)
>
> ...

I do not find the function in `ftfy` appealing.  The documentation does not say so, but it appears to be designed to handle both `surrogateescape` and ... be part of a workaround for [CESU-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8), or something like that?

> **Replace 16-bit surrogate codepoints with the characters they represent (when properly paired)**, or with � otherwise.