# Yet another person who can't figure how to use unicode in Python

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

I know there is tons of question about this, but somehow I could not find a solution to my problem (in python3) :

```
toto="//\udcc3\udca0"
fp = open('cool', 'w')
fp.write(toto)
```

I get:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udcc3' in position 2: surrogates not allowed
```

How can I make it work?

Some precision: the string `"//\udcc3\udca0"` is given to me and I have no control over it. `'\udcc3\udca0'` is supposed to represent the character `'à'`.

Comment: Why are you using surrogates? What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you want to do raw data: `toto = b"//\udcc3\udca0"; fp = open('cool', 'wb')`

Comment: `\udcc3\udca0` is not a legal UTF-16 surrogate pair.  What's the character you're intending to write?

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38147966/8353711).

Comment: I don't want to write bytes, I want to write strings. The string 'à' got transformed in '\udcc3\udca0' by a process over which I don't have control. But at the end I would like to write 'à' or '\udcc3\udca0'. But everything I try keeps producing exceptions...

Comment: How are you receiving the string?

Comment: The string is written on the standard output with 'echo' and piped to the python program. It seems that this is where 'à' becomes '\udcc3\udca0'

Comment: @Archimondain: Which OS and Python version are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `'\udcc3\udca0'` is supposed to represent the character `'à'`

The proper way to write `'à'` using Python Unicode escapes is `'\u00E0'`.  Its UTF-8 encoding is `b'\xc3\xa0'`.

It seems that whatever process produced your string was trying to use the UTF-8 representation, but instead of properly converting it to a Unicode string, it put the individual bytes in the U+DC*xx* range used by Python 3's [surrogateescape](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0383/) convention.

```
>>> 'à'.encode('UTF-8').decode('ASCII', 'surrogateescape')
'\udcc3\udca0'
```

To fix the string, invert the operations that mangled it.

```
toto="//\udcc3\udca0"
toto = toto.encode('ASCII', 'surrogateescape').decode('UTF-8')
# At this point, toto == '//à', as intended.
fp = open('cool', 'w')
fp.write(toto)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer to a somewhat weird issue. I feel that I should treat the cause rather than the disease. I'm not sure how I end up with the wrong '\udcc3\udca0' in the process. I suspect that it comes from the following erlang call `:os.cmd(to_charlist "echo à")`. I will investigate...

Comment: I finally solved the issue : it was docker who was messing up with my strings. I needed to add "ENV LANG C.UTF-8" and "ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8" in the conf