# In Python 3, how do you remove all non-UTF8 characters from a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, decode, encode

I'm using Python 3.7.  How do I remove all non-UTF-8 characters from a string?  I tried using "lambda x: x.decode('utf-8','ignore').encode("utf-8")" in the below

```
coop_types = map(
    lambda x: x.decode('utf-8','ignore').encode("utf-8"),
    filter(None, set(d['type'] for d in input_file))
)
```

but this is resulting in the error ...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/parse_coop_csv.py", line 30, in <module>
    for coop_type in coop_types:
  File "scripts/parse_coop_csv.py", line 25, in <lambda>
    lambda x: x.decode('utf-8','ignore').encode("utf-8"),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

If you have a generic way to remove all non-UTF8 chars from a string, that's all I'm looking for.

Comment: You first *encode* `x`, *then* decode it. `str.encode` takes a Unicode string and produces a UTF-8 encoding of it. `bytes.decode` takes a string and attempts interpret it as an encoding to produce a `str` object.

Comment: Can you give an example of what would be a non-UTF-8 character in an instance of `str`? Do you mean surrogate code points?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're starting with a string. You can't `decode` a `str` (it's already decoded text, you can only encode it to binary data again). UTF-8 encodes almost any valid Unicode text (which is what `str` stores) so this shouldn't come up much, but if you're encountering [surrogate characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates) in your input, you could just reverse the directions, changing:

```
x.decode('utf-8','ignore').encode("utf-8")
```

to:

```
x.encode('utf-8','ignore').decode("utf-8")
```

where you encode any UTF-8 encodable thing, discarding the unencodable stuff, then decode the now clean UTF-8 bytes.

Comment: Side-note: If the problem is surrogates, you may not want to discard them; you may just need to [accept them properly (e.g. via `json.loads` or the like)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38147259/364696) in the first place, so you never actually see them, you just see the single Unicode character they represent.

Comment: so long as you're familiar with your input data and outcome of loosing chars beyond byte 127, then this is a great choice - perhaps one of the simplest I've found in this topic. good job, @ShadowRanger

Comment: @NathanBenton: To be clear, this doesn't lose all characters beyond byte 127 (if you used `'ascii'` as the encoding instead of `'utf-8'` it would). UTF-8 handles all normal Unicode ordinals, just not [high-low surrogates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates) (a UTF-16 thing that doesn't apply to UTF-8).

Comment: got it - thank you for the feedback and correction, @ShadowRanger