# Encode wrong formated emojis in python

Tags: python, unicode, emoji

### EDIT

I've a text file containing sentences including emojis that I cannot handle correctly.

My csv file contains those sentences :

- Je suis sur que certaines personnes vont faire la file pour toucher cette borne unicode-d83d\ude02
- Aurelie Gouverneur voir même la lechée peut être unicode-d83d\ude02unicode-d83d\ude02unicode-d83e\udd2e
- Mélanie Ham même ce prendre en photo avec unicode-d83e\udd23

My code :

```
df_test=pd.read_csv("myfile.csv", sep=';',index_col=None, encoding="utf-8")

for item, row in df_test.iterrows():
    print(repr(row["Message"]))
    s=row["Message"]
    s = re.sub(r'unicode-([0-9a-f]{4})',lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1),16)),s)
    s = s.encode('utf16','surrogatepass').decode('utf16')
```

The printed results :

```
'Je suis sur que certaines personnes vont faire la file pour toucher cette borne unicode-d83d\\ude02'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-e3c423a15acd> in <module>
      5     s=row["Message"]
      6     s = re.sub(r'unicode-([0-9a-f]{4})',lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1),16)),s)
----> 7     s = s.encode('utf16','surrogatepass').decode('utf16')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 162-163: illegal UTF-16 surrogate
```

The issue is probably related to the encoding when I load the csv into a dataframe, but I've no idea how to solve this...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to work with surrogate pairs in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147259/how-to-work-with-surrogate-pairs-in-python)

Comment: Unfortunatly, I tried this solution but it doesn't work for me... I started by replacing "unicode-" to "\u". But it writes "\\ud83d\ude44" which is not understood as emoji by encode / decode functions

Comment: I'm going to have to ask *what you exactly got*. Literal bytes, please. Currently your post contains `"This is some text and emoji **unicode-d83d\ude44**"`, which is ambiguous enough. Are the stars part of it? (I guess not -- but I can guess all day long.) No backslash before `d83d`? A single backslash before `ude44` -- or, is it? Or is it part of Python's string `repr`? Only you can tell us.

Comment: I have a string. str = "This is some text and emoji unicode-d83d\ude44". My objective is to turn "unicode-d83d\ude44" into "\ud83d\ude44", so I could print the emoji using "\ud83d\ude44".encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass').decode('utf-16')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text is a combination of a Unicode escape and a custom syntax.  This will decode as described by capturing the hexadecimal values of the two escape codes, then formatting them into a JSON-formatted pair of surrogates and letting that module convert to the correct Unicode code point.

```
#coding:utf8
import re
import json

sentences = [r'Je suis sur que certaines personnes vont faire la file pour toucher cette borne unicode-d83d\ude02',
             r'Aurelie Gouverneur voir même la lechée peut être unicode-d83d\ude02unicode-d83d\ude02unicode-d83e\udd2e',
             r'Mélanie Ham même ce prendre en photo avec unicode-d83e\udd23']

def surrogates_to_unicode(m):
    upper = int(m.group(1),16)
    lower = int(m.group(2),16)
    return json.loads(f'"\\u{upper:04x}\\u{lower:04x}"')

for s in sentences:
    s = re.sub(r'unicode-([0-9a-f]{4})\\u([0-9a-f]{4})',surrogates_to_unicode,s)
    print(s)
```

```
Je suis sur que certaines personnes vont faire la file pour toucher cette borne 
Aurelie Gouverneur voir même la lechée peut être 
Mélanie Ham même ce prendre en photo avec
```

Comment: actually, my input file is a csv that I load into a dataframe. My understanding is that the CSV has been saved by a java program which encode the emojis into a java standard (ex : unicode-d83d\ude44). But, when I load my csv in a python dataframe, those emojis are encoded as a string and not unicode characters...

Comment: @Erwan that’s no standard I’ve ever seen. Why aren’t both surrogates using \u escapes?

Comment: Thank you so much !!!! :) Honestly I don't know why they formated the emojis like this....

Comment: I've still some difficulties to load a csv containing those wrong formated emojis.  The error code says : UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 162-163: illegal UTF-16 surrogate 
`df_test=pd.read_csv("myfile.csv", sep=';',index_col=None, encoding="utf-8")
for item, row in df_test.iterrows():
    print(row["Message"])
    s=row["Message"]
    print(s)
    s = re.sub(r'unicode-([0-9a-f]{4})',lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1),16)),s)
    s = s.encode('utf16','surrogatepass').decode('utf16')
    print(s)`

Comment: @Erwan Edit your question with your example. Be precise on the content of the string that fails. Use `repr()` to display.

Comment: I've edited my question with more details. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Erwan Updated.  The problem with the original answer is it didn't take into account that the second surrogate wasn't a Unicode code point but another Unicode escape.  JSON would have been a better format for the original sentences.