# How to convert unicode of an emoji into CLDR Short Name

Tags: python, unicode, emoji, extract, data-extraction

I am using python to extract comments and display them. 
It looks like this when I print it.

```
This was heart wrenching \u2764\ufe0f
Amazing compassion \ud83d\udc9c\ud83d\udc9c\ud83d\udc9c #tears
\u2764\ufe0f\u2764\ufe0f\u2764\ufe0f
```

How do I convert the unicodes of the emojis into its respective CLDR Short Name?
For example, U+1F44D will print as thumbs up.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** I think I found solution for problem with codes `\ud83d\udc9c`

```
text = text.encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass').decode('utf-16')
```

It converts surrogate value `\ud83d\udc9c` to correct emoji value `\U0001f49c`

Source: [How to work with surrogate pairs in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147259/how-to-work-with-surrogate-pairs-in-python)

Wikipedia: [Surrogate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates)

Other: [Unicode character inspector](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%F0%9F%99%8F)

---

Using Google I found

```
print('\U0001F44D'.encode('ascii', 'namereplace').decode())
```

Result

```
\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}
```

And

```
import unicodedata

print(unicodedata.name('\U0001F44D'))
```

Result:

```
THUMBS UP SIGN
```

So it is good to use `Google` before you ask on Stackoverflow.

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

---

The same for text

```
text = '''This was heart wrenching \u2764\ufe0f
Amazing compassion \ud83d\udc9c\ud83d\udc9c\ud83d\udc9c #tears
\u2764\ufe0f\u2764\ufe0f\u2764\ufe0f'''

print(text.encode('ascii', 'namereplace').decode())
```

Result:

```
This was heart wrenching \N{HEAVY BLACK HEART}\N{VARIATION SELECTOR-16}
Amazing compassion \ud83d\udc9c\ud83d\udc9c\ud83d\udc9c #tears
\N{HEAVY BLACK HEART}\N{VARIATION SELECTOR-16}\N{HEAVY BLACK HEART}\N{VARIATION SELECTOR-16}\N{HEAVY BLACK HEART}\N{VARIATION SELECTOR-16}
\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}
```

Now you may have to remove `\N{` and `}`

But it has problem with `\ud83d\udc9c\ud83d\udc9c\ud83d\udc9c`

---

You can use `unicodedata` in `for`-loop to get names for every char in text but it may have problem if it has no name ie. `'\n'`. And it gives names also for normal chars so you may have to use `unicodedata.category()` to decide which chars to replace.

This also has problem with `\ud83d\udc9c\ud83d\udc9c\ud83d\udc9c`

```
import unicodedata

# http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#General_Category_Values

for char in text:
    try:
        print(char, '|', unicodedata.category(char), '|', unicodedata.name(char))
    except ValueError:
        print(repr(char), '| (repr)')
```

Result:

```
T | Lu | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
h | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER H
i | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER I
s | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER S
  | Zs | SPACE
w | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER W
a | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER A
s | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER S
  | Zs | SPACE
h | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER H
e | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER E
a | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER A
r | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER R
t | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER T
  | Zs | SPACE
w | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER W
r | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER R
e | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER E
n | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER N
c | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER C
h | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER H
i | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER I
n | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER N
g | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER G
  | Zs | SPACE
❤ | So | HEAVY BLACK HEART
️ | Mn | VARIATION SELECTOR-16
'\n' | (repr)
A | Lu | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
m | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER M
a | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER A
z | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER Z
i | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER I
n | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER N
g | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER G
  | Zs | SPACE
c | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER C
o | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER O
m | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER M
p | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER P
a | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER A
s | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER S
s | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER S
i | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER I
o | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER O
n | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER N
  | Zs | SPACE
'\ud83d' | (repr)
'\udc9c' | (repr)
'\ud83d' | (repr)
'\udc9c' | (repr)
'\ud83d' | (repr)
'\udc9c' | (repr)
  | Zs | SPACE
# | Po | NUMBER SIGN
t | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER T
e | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER E
a | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER A
r | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER R
s | Ll | LATIN SMALL LETTER S
'\n' | (repr)
❤ | So | HEAVY BLACK HEART
️ | Mn | VARIATION SELECTOR-16
❤ | So | HEAVY BLACK HEART
️ | Mn | VARIATION SELECTOR-16
❤ | So | HEAVY BLACK HEART
️ | Mn | VARIATION SELECTOR-16
```

---

Because it has problem with `\ud83d\udc9c\ud83d\udc9c\ud83d\udc9c` so I replace it with `?`

```
import unicodedata

text = '''This was heart wrenching \u2764\ufe0f
Amazing compassion \ud83d\udc9c\ud83d\udc9c\ud83d\udc9c #tears
\u2764\ufe0f\u2764\ufe0f\u2764\ufe0f'''

result = []

for char in text:
    if unicodedata.category(char) in ('So', 'Mn'):
        result.append(':{}:'.format(unicodedata.name(char)))
    elif unicodedata.category(char) in ('Cs'):
        result.append('?') #char)
    else:
        result.append(char)

print(''.join(result))
```

Result:

```
This was heart wrenching :HEAVY BLACK HEART::VARIATION SELECTOR-16:
Amazing compassion ?????? #tears
:HEAVY BLACK HEART::VARIATION SELECTOR-16::HEAVY BLACK HEART::VARIATION SELECTOR-16::HEAVY BLACK HEART::VARIATION SELECTOR-16:
```

---

**EDIT:** using Google again I found external module [emoji](https://pypi.org/project/emoji/) which can convert some names but it also has problem with `\ud83d\udc9c`  so I used `repr` to display it - but it also print new line as `\n`

```
text = '''This was heart wrenching \u2764\ufe0f
Amazing compassion \ud83d\udc9c\ud83d\udc9c\ud83d\udc9c #tears
\u2764\ufe0f\u2764\ufe0f\u2764\ufe0f'''

import emoji

#print( repr(emoji.demojize(text, use_aliases=True)) ) 
print( repr(emoji.demojize(text)) )
```

Result:

```
'This was heart wrenching :heart:\nAmazing compassion \ud83d\udc9c\ud83d\udc9c\ud83d\udc9c #tears\n:heart::heart::heart:'
```

---

http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

https://www.webfx.com/tools/emoji-cheat-sheet/

http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/12.0/emoji-test.txt

---

**BTW:** I found module [demoji](https://pypi.org/project/demoji/) which can find emoji and gives names. But it also has problem with code `\ud83d\udc9c`

```
import demoji

# run only once after installing module
demoji.download_codes()

print(demoji.findall(text))
```

It needs `demoji.download_codes()` only once - after installing module.

Result:

```
{'❤️': 'red heart'}
```

---

If you get it as JSON data `"\ud83d\udc9c"` then you shouldn't have problem - it should convert it automatically

```
import json

# escaped unicode in " "  
data = r'"\ud83d\udc9c"' 
print(json.loads(data))
```

In other situation you would have to convert it

```
# convert to escaped unicode and put in " "  
data = '"{}"'.format('\ud83d\udc9c'.encode('unicode-escape').decode())
print(json.loads(data))
```

[How to work with surrogate pairs in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147259/how-to-work-with-surrogate-pairs-in-python)