# Convert unicode emojis to a format I can use with chromedriver

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, selenium-chromedriver, python-unicode

I've tried to convert a string like

```
"What was he thinking \ud83d\ude02"
```

into a format I can use with the `chromedriver.send_keys` function.
Converting them into emojis does not work, because `chromedriver` only supports characters in the BMP format.

sorry for any spelling mistakes, I'm German :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to work with surrogate pairs in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147259/how-to-work-with-surrogate-pairs-in-python)

Comment: this is not the problem. the problem is, that chromedriver wont let me "send_keys" with a grapic version of the emoji