# How to convert unicode string to bytes Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, unicode, byte

I have a string which I get from a function

```
>>> example = Some_function()
```

This Some_function return a very long combination of Unicode and ASCII string like `'gn1\ud123a\ud123\ud123\ud123\ud919\ud123\ud123'`
My Problem is that when I try to convert this unicode string to bytes it gives me an error that `\ud919` cannot be encoded by `utf-8`. I tried :

```
>>> further=bytes(example,encoding='utf-8')
```

`Note:` I cannot ignore this \ud919. If there is a way to solve this problem or how can I convert `'gn1\ud123a\ud123\ud123\ud123\ud919\ud123\ud123'` to `'gn1\ud123a\ud123\ud123\ud123\\ud919\ud123\ud123'` to treat \ud919 as simple string not unicode.

Answer (score 0):

based on the version.
print type(unicode_string), repr(unicode_string) Python 3.x : print type(unicode_string), ascii(unicode_string)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

`\ud919` is a [surrogate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147259/how-to-work-with-surrogate-pairs-in-python) character, one does not simply convert it. Use `surrogatepass` flag:

```
'gn1\ud123a\ud123\ud123\ud123\ud919\ud123\ud123'.encode('utf-8', 'surrogatepass')
>>> b'gn1\xed\x84\xa3a\xed\x84\xa3\xed\x84\xa3\xed\x84\xa3\xed\xa4\x99\xed\x84\xa3\xed\x84\xa3'
```